# Do Baptists Celebrate Ascension Day?

Tags: baptist, ascension, celebrations

As a general rule, do Baptists mark Ascension Day? I'm think particularly of the Thursday, but if attention is typically drawn on a Sunday either side. Many countries have Ascension Day as a bank holiday, and many churches consider Ascension Day to be a major feast day. Do Baptists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baptists are by definition very independent. Each congregation sets its own beliefs, processes and celebrations, even if they belong to a larger denominational organization.

In general though Baptists celebrate very few festivals, typically limited to Christmas and Easter. Ascension day is not one, and is certainly not a "major festival". The situation may be different in places where Ascension Day is a public holiday, but given the number of Baptists who do not hold a church service on Christmas day I suspect not.